# How to mark notes as unread?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I think most people have faced this already, we have notes that we do NOT want to attend to their subject atm, but they are AUTOMATICALLY marked as read and we CANNOT undo that, what is utterly annoying...

We cannot also drop unwanted notes, is it safe to drop them? wont break quests?

I believe the answer must be in one of these lines: console commands, mod, savegame editor, any other smarty hack that can do the trick; as I cannot find any normal way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop them and still do their quests. No idea on how to unread them though.